# C++ Memory Management: Who is responsible

Tags: c++, memory-management

Suppose I am writing a C++ class. The class has the following fields:

- An integer.
- a C++ string
- dynamically resizable integer array and a pointer to it.

In the destructor, I know I have to `delete` anything that I had earlier claimed by calling `new`. In this case, I know I have to free the space I used for the int array. What about the string's memory? I know I'm not responsible for releasing its memory, because I didn't call `new` to allocate it, but how does it get freed? When does C++ call its destructor?

Comment: when it goes out of scope, just like your the destructor of your class.

Comment: Incidentally, you should replace your "dynamically resizable integer array" with a `std::vector<int>` instance - now you don't even have to delete the array, and you probably can omit your destructor altogether. Remember the single responsibility principle: your class should be responsible for whatever it is designed to do, leaving memory management to to classes written for that specific scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What about the string's memory? I know I'm not responsible for releasing its memory, because I didn't call new to allocate it, but how does it get freed?

Your class's destructor implicitly calls `std::string`'s destructor which in turn handles the freeing of its own resources. Nothing else to worry.

> When does C++ call its destructor?

When your class' object's destructor is called. That means when that object goes out of scope or `delete` has been called on a pointer to it when it has been created by `new`.

I somehow understand your problem. You may think that `new` recursively `new`s the members of your class. No. It doesn't do it that way. Unless your class itself does `new` on the member variables will you need to call `delete` on them.

Answer (score 2):

Destructors of member variables are automatically called once the instance destructor has completed.

Comment: Are they called before or after the instance destructor? Won't it lose the pointer to it once the instance destructor is called?

Comment: @user2380088: Not really.  You can imagine that the compiler secretly adds the code `mystring.~string();` to the end of the body of your destructor.

Comment: ... and for derived classes, it adds the call to `Base::~Base()` last. It's very intentionally in reverse order of construction.

Answer (score 1):

That memory is reclaimed when the variable goes out of scope.

Comment: To be pedantic, "scope" is a property of *names* (i.e. symbols that the programmer interacts with).  We're talking about objects here, so "lifetime" is the relevant concept...